# Image slideshow with moviepy

Tags: python, moviepy

I am trying to make a basic image slideshow using `moviepy`.

Ive am to display a single image but am trying to work out how to make multiple images show up after each other and add a duration to each.

I have this:

```
clip1 = ImageClip('image.jpg').set_duration(10)
clip1.write_videofile("test.mp4", fps=24)
```

I have noticed some code using this: `final = CompositeVideoClip([ukulele,txt_mov,piano])`

From what I understand, `CompositeVideoClip` simply overlays the arguments?

How would I go about creating an image slideshow? Would I use some sort of concatenation?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Worked it out for myself.

```
from moviepy.editor import *

ic_1 = ImageClip('image1.jpg').set_duration(2)
ic_2 = ImageClip('image2.jpg').set_duration(1)

video = concatenate([ic_1, ic_2], method="compose")
video.write_videofile('test.mp4', fps=24)
```